# why the project pom.xml is showing this Non-Resolvable error

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

[Dont know whats wrong here. I cloned the project form the bitbucket repo. Upon importing the project as a existing maven project this is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sbp6.png)

Comment: You seemed to be having network issues (timeouts) I assume you are behind a proxy/firewall ?

Comment: can you please add the full pom.xml here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the snapshot version of the spring boot and these dependencies are not available on the maven central so have to add the additional repository address.

Add the following snippets in the `<project>` component in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```